# Flutter - Data from json api to be listed in drop down list

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to fetch the data from json api and to be listed in the drop down list but i am hitting with **The method 'map' was called on null** error.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "Hospital Management",
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _mySelection;

  final String url = "http://webmyls.com/php/getdata.php";

  List data;

  Future<String> getSWData() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

    setState(() {
      data = resBody;
    });

    print(resBody);

    return "Sucess";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getSWData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hospital Management"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new DropdownButton(
          items: data.map((item) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem(
              child: new Text(item['item_name']),
              value: item['id'].toString(),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (newVal) {
            setState(() {
              _mySelection = newVal;
            });
          },
          value: _mySelection,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error from the debug consol

```
flutter: The method 'map' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(Closure: 
(dynamic) => DropdownMenuItem<String>)
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      Object.noSuchMethod 
(dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:48:5)
```

I am expecting to show the list of data from the json api in the drop down menu. I am beginner to dart and flutter. Help me out to solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is not initialized. It is set on `getSWData` which is `async`.

A possible solution could be to have `data` as **emptyList** as an initial value.

```
List data = List();
```

If you want to display `DropdownButton` based on data, you can use [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and show **loader** or something till data comes from `getSWData`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you please help me out with the updated code. I am newbie to Flutter and dart.

Answer (score 0):

Your Api http://webmyls.com/php/getdata.php returns a list not a map. Hence, it cannot have direct property `advisor_report`. Consider removing it.

Data should be changed inside `setState`.

You never called `getSWData()`

Below is more improved example.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "Hospital Management",
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _mySelection;

  final String url = "http://webmyls.com/php/getdata.php";

  List data;

  Future<String> getSWData() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

    setState(() {
      data = resBody;
    });

    print(resBody);

    return "Sucess";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getSWData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hospital Management"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new DropdownButton(
          items: data.map((item) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem(
              child: new Text(item['item_name']),
              value: item['id'].toString(),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (newVal) {
            setState(() {
              _mySelection = newVal;
            });
          },
          value: _mySelection,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I tried updating the code as mentioned in your comments but still i am facing the same error.

Comment: I used the same code as you have mentioned in your answer